# Loop through all children of in a firebase database key

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have a webapp where i save some values from inputs to the firebase database with this line:

```
fire.database().ref('gamehomeitems').push( dataset );
```

the dataset includes a "category", "value1" and "value2".

on another page, i want to render all the children saved in the 'gamehomeitems' part of my firebase database, but im not able to loop through them and get their values

what would be the appropriate code to render the category of all the children in 'gamehomeitems'?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked many times before and is covered in the documentation for [Working with Lists of Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data). But here is a bundled example of **one way** to achieve what you want.

Assuming this is your table:

```html
<table style="width:100%" id="gamehomeitems-table">
  <tr id="gamehomeitems-headerrow">
    <th>Category:</th>
    <th>Home Team:</th> 
    <th>Away Team:</th>
  </tr>
</table>

<!-- at the bottom of the body -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script>
  firebase.initializeApp(/* ... */);
  
  const gameHomeItemsRef = firebase.database().ref("gamehomeitems");
  const gameHomeItemsTbl = document.getElementById("gamehomeitems-table");
  const gameHomeItemsQuery = gameHomeItemsRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(20); // get 20 most recent entries

  const gameHomeItemsChildAddedCallback =
    gameHomeItemsQuery
      .on('child_added', function(snapshot, keyOfPreviousRow) {
        const rowData = snapshot.val();
        let rowContent = '<tr id="item-' + snapshot.key + '">';
        rowContent += "<td>" + rowData.category + "</td>";
        rowContent += "<td>" + rowData.value1 + "</td>";
        rowContent += "<td>" + rowData.value2 + "</td>";
        rowContent += "</tr>";
        
        gameHomeItemsTbl.append(rowContent);
        
        // todo: make sure this row is inserted above the row for "keyOfPreviousRow" if newest at the top is required.
        //       currently it will be oldest at the top, newest at the bottom
      });
      
  const gameHomeItemsChildChangedCallback =
    gameHomeItemsQuery
      .on('child_changed', function(snapshot, keyOfPreviousRow) {
        // todo: find row with id "item-KEY" and update it's data in the table
      });
      
  const gameHomeItemsChildRemovedCallback =
    gameHomeItemsQuery
      .on('child_removed', function(snapshot) {
        // todo: find row with id "item-KEY" and remove it from the table
      });
    
  // later, when you no longer need the table to be updated live
  // gameHomeItemsRef.off("child_added", gameHomeItemsChildAddedCallback);
  // gameHomeItemsRef.off("child_changed", gameHomeItemsChildChangedCallback);
  // gameHomeItemsRef.off("child_removed", gameHomeItemsChildRemovedCallback);

  // todo: implement "child_moved" when not using orderByKey()
</script>
```